# .htaccess Set Default Page for each Sub-Directory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

quick question:

Using tutorials I have been able to redirect my domain name to point to a different page other than the index.php

However I cannot find any tutorials or reference material to help me in changing the default page for a particular sub-directory.

For example, I want www.url.com/admin to redirect to www.url.com/adming/login whilst still showing www.url.com/admin in the address bar.

I'm sure this must be fairly simple but I can't quite get my head around in.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place this rule in `/admin/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /admin/

RewriteRule ^$ login [L]
```

Comment: That's a big help, I didn't realise you could have a separate htaccess in each subdirectory. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome, yes you can have .htaccess in all the subdirectories if you want.